# SDL and Sudoku : resizing SDL_Surface

Tags: sdl

I have to take a photo of a sudoku grid, then I have to save all the cell of the grid.

I have to use for another algorithm, SDL_Surface of 28x28 pixels for each cell, but I don't know how to do that because the photo I took could be larger than that, or smaller than that. I had a look on SDL_BlitSurface but I have to use SDL1 so it doesn't work, and with SDL_SoftStretch I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here :
https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/640043-scaling-images/

So here is the main part of it :

```
double zoomx = newwidth  / (float)image->w;
double zoomy = newheight / (float)image->h;

// This function assumes no smoothing, so that any colorkeys wont bleed.
SDL_Surface* sized = zoomSurface( image, zoomx, zoomy, SMOOTHING_OFF );
```

To use zoomSurface, it needs to :

- add `#include "SDL/SDL_rotozoom.h"` at the beginning of the file.
- use the following option with gcc : `-lSDL_gfx`.